# How to handle checkbox with node, mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, post, mongoose

This is the `ejs` file with a form that contains multiple checkbox inputs by looping through a database.And sends a post request, which is then handled by `app.post`

```
    <form action="/" method="post">
    <% users.forEach(function(user) { %>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                      <input type="checkbox" value="<%= user.username %>" name="username">
                    </td>
                  </tr>
    <% }) %>
    </form>
```

So when the user checks just one checkbox it can be handled just by this on the `app.post()`:

```
    users = req.body.username
        if (typeof users == 'string') {
            User.findOne({"username":users}, function(err, foundUser) {
                if(err) {console.log(err)}
                else {
                    if (foundUser) {
                        res.render("queuedUsers", {users: foundUser})
                    }
                }
            })
```

But if the user checks multiple checkboxes than it returns a list. But I can't loop through the list and `res.render` multiple times as it will throw a header already sent error. How to handle this??

```
    else {
        users.forEach(function(user) {
            User.findOne({"username":user}, function(err, foundUser) {
                if(err) {console.log(err)}
                else {
                    if(foundUser) {
                        
                    }
                }
            })
        })
```

I'm still new to web development. If more info is needed please ask. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
users = req.body.username
if (typeof users == 'string') {
    User.findOne({ "username": users }, function(err, foundUser) {
        if (err) { console.log(err) } else {
            if (foundUser) {
                res.render("queuedUsers", { users: foundUser })
            }
        }
    })
} else {
    users.forEach(function(user) {
        User.findOne({ "username": user }, function(err, foundUser) {
            if (err) { console.log(err) } else {
                if (foundUser) {}
            }
        })
    })
}
```

use this:

```
// if users is string make it an array
if (typeof users == 'string')
    users = [users];

// then you only need a single User.find and no if/else statement
// use $in operator to find all users in one query
User.find({"username": { $in: users }}, function(err, foundUsers) {
    if(err) // render error page
        return res.render('500');

    res.render("queuedUsers", { users: foundUsers || [] });
})
```